# Is there a way I can create a string out of some text and a parameter list?

Tags: c#

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
 var a = "Hello 123";
```

but instead code it like this:

```
 var id = 123;
 var a = xxxx("Hello ?", id);
```

Is there some function I can replace the xxxx with that will help me to do this in C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is.

`String.Format("Hello {0}", id);`

String format uses numbered indexes to bind data into the string.

And as of C# 6 onwards you can use the following string interpolation:

```
var a = $"Hello {id}";
```

Answer (score 2):

If I take that literally, replacing the `?`:

```
 string a = "Hello ?".Replace("?", id.ToString());
```

but normally we do

```
 string a = String.Format("Hello {0}", id);
```

or

```
 string a = $"Hello {id}";
```

Comment: He doesn't want to replace all question marks. It's really just a placeholder for what should be inserted instead.

Comment: @Rango - how do you know that?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? `var a = "Hello 123";` should become `var id = 123; var a = xxxx("Hello ?", id);` where `xxxx` is the method and `?` the single value that should be replaced with the variable value.

Answer (score 2):

```
var id = 123;
var a = $"Hello {id}";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either concatenate using +:

```
var a = "Hello " + id;
```

string.Format:

```
var a = string.Format("Hello {0}", id);
```

or string interpolation:

```
var a = $"Hello {id}";
```